# Fastest way to index and query huge tab delimited file

Tags: mongodb, performance, bigdata, database

I have 30Gb tab-delimited text file with numbers, I need the fastest way index it and to do a query to it by first and second column. I've tried MongoDB but it takes huge time to upload data to database, I've tried mongoimport via json file but it takes huge amount of time.

> mongoimport --upsert --upsertFields A,B,S1,E1,S2,E2 -d DBName -c
>   TableName data.json

Data file fragment:

```
504 246 91.92007 93 0 4657 5631 5911 0 39 1061 1162
813 469 92.14697 109 0 2057 2665 7252 1 363 961 1399
2388 987 92.20945 61 0 1183 1575 1824 0 66 560 5088
2388 2323 92.88472 129 0 75 1161 1824 1 2516 3592 12488
2729 1008 95.29058 47 0 435 1166 1193 1 76 654 1055
2757 76 94.25837 12 0 0 44 1946 0 51 68 247
2757 2089 92.63158 14 0 12 30 1946 0 14 30 211
```

What is the right efficient way to do it with minimum time? Any hints about the best database for it? Or about mongo upload speed optimisation?

Query examples:

```
objs = db.TableName.find({'A':2757})
objs = db.TableName.find({'B':76})
```

For each number in column A and B there are up to 1000 hits with the mean 20.

Comment: How often do you want to query? Do you have an example query?

Comment: 30Gb / 50 = 600Mtuples ! How long is is taking to upload, and to make the indexes?

Comment: Is your question on the speed of import, the speed of querying, or both? FYI, the `mongoimport` tool in MongoDB 2.6 is single threaded so isn't the fastest approach for importing a large data set. For the upcoming release of MongoDB 2.8, command line tools have been rewritten in Go for improved performance and concurrency. MongoDB 2.8 is still in release candidate stage at the moment (15-Dec-2015) however you could try the new `mongoimport` for comparison. For speed of querying you need to provide more info, starting with output of your queries with .explain(true). Also, your MongoDB version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases often has complex work to do in order to be more robust.

If you use strait B-tree indexes, normally it is faster.

Following you'll find a upload script in perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DB_File;
use Fcntl ;

# $DB_BTREE->{'cachesize'} = 1000000;
$DB_BTREE->{'flags'} = R_DUP ;

my (%h, %h1, %h2,$n);

my $x = tie %h,  'DB_File', "bf.db", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC , 0640, $DB_BTREE;
my $x1= tie %h1, 'DB_File', "i1.db", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC , 0640, $DB_BTREE;
my $x2= tie %h2, 'DB_File', "i2.db", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC , 0640, $DB_BTREE;

while(<>){ chomp;
  if(/(\d+)\s+(\d+)/){
    $h{++$n}=$_;           ##  add the tup
    $h1{$1} = $n;          ##  add to index1
    $h2{$2} = $n           ##  add to index2;
  }
}

untie %h;
untie %h1;
untie %h2;
```

and a query:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DB_File;
use Fcntl ;
$DB_BTREE->{'flags'} = R_DUP ;

my (%h, %h1, %h2, $n, @list);

my $x = tie %h,  'DB_File', "bf.db", O_RDWR|O_CREAT , 0640, $DB_BTREE;
my $x1= tie %h1, 'DB_File', "i1.db", O_RDWR|O_CREAT , 0640, $DB_BTREE;
my $x2= tie %h2, 'DB_File', "i2.db", O_RDWR|O_CREAT , 0640, $DB_BTREE;

while(<>){ chomp;                    # Queries input format:   A:number or B:number
  if(/A:(\d+)/){
      @list = sort $x1->get_dup($1) ;
      for(@list){print $h{$_},"\n"; }
  }
  if(/B:(\d+)/){
      @list = sort $x2->get_dup($1) ;
      for(@list){print $h{$_},"\n"; }
  }
}
```

Query is very fast.

But upload took 20s (user time) for 1 000 000 lines...

(please if you do experiments with your data, show us the times)